# fixed length Vector can be spliced without throwing an exception -- is this intentional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, splice, indexoutofrangeexception

According to [**Adobe documentation**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#fixed), if a Vector has been set to have a fixed length then

> **fixed** (Boolean) : 
>  Indicates whether the length property of the Vector can be changed. If the value is true, the length property
>   can't be changed. This means the following operations are not allowed
>   when fixed is true:
>
> - setting the length property directly
> - assigning a value to index position length
> - calling a method that changes the length property, including:
>
>   - `pop()`
>   - `push()`
>   - `shift()`
>   - `unshift()`
>   - `splice()` (if the `splice()` call changes the length of the Vector).

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#fixed

Unfortunately, this appears to be **not true**. I had a `splice()` call in some code I was reworking and I found that a Vector with fixed length was actually not throwing an error (which was sort of the point, because I wanted to make sure no such calls were being made). I eventually found the offending line of code, but a properly thrown exception would have been nice...

Am I missing something? Everything but `splice()` will throw an exception. But I can willfully change the length of a fixed-length Vector using `splice()` which makes me question the point of it all. Is it possible my runtime environment is configured wrong? Am I reading the wrong documentation? Any insight or advice would be great.

Comment: I checked it and it is exactly as you say: **splice** does not raise an exception although according to the official documentation it should. So, (1) did you, as you should've done, submit a bug report (or discover the bug is already known) to Adobe and (2) other than *oh look Flash Player has a buuuuug* attitude, is there a problem?

Comment: I haven't submitted a bug yet. It's been so long since AS3 came out that I figured I would check if it was a strict mode setting, OS dependent, compiler dependent, runtime dependent, or something, anything, I didn't know about. It's not the end of the world, but it's something I have to be careful of now since I can't rely on fixed length as a means to alert me to improper manipulation of the data.

Comment: I checked it again. The bug is persistent with Flash Players from 10.3 through 25. Which probably means the severity of the bug between *low* and *very low* is somewhere at the point *who friggin cares*. The point is, the beginner developer would rather use **Array** than **Vector**, while the one who'd use strong-typed **Vector** along with **fixed** would probably not try to **splice** it, let alone to rely on the exception this should raise.